# How can I copy members of one local group to another local group using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I know you cannot nest local groups within local groups so I would like to see if there's a way to copy all members of one local group to another local group in PowerShell.

I've tried the PowerShell script below but it fails...

```bsh
$newGrpName = "NewTestGroup"
$description = "New Test Group"
$existingGrpName = "TechUsers"


Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "NewTestGroup" -Members (Get-LocalGroupMember $existingGrpName) `
Get-LocalGroupMember | Select Name
```

Error:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument 'Get-LocalGroupMember'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "NewTestGroup" -Member (Get-LocalGrou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-LocalGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemberComma
```

I want all the members of "TechUsers" group to be copied into "NewTestGroup" group.

Comment: Try: `Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $existingGrpName | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "NewTestGroup"`

Comment: @jrider just curious why you didn't post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @JayAdams I wasn't for certain if you could pipe into `Add-LocalGroupMember`. I know you can in `Add-ADGroupMember`. I didn't want to give an uncertain answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pipe `Get-LocalGroupMember` into `Add-LocalGroupMember`

Example:

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $existingGrpName | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "NewTestGroup"
```